# Add a term to list in block editor taxonomy sidebar

Tags: custom-taxonomy, block-editor

I'm the author of a plugin called [Radio Buttons for taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/) which converts certain taxonomy metaboxes (in classic) and sidebars (block editor) to use Radio buttons instead of checkboxes for selecting a term.

Unlike with checkboxes, which you can simply uncheck, with radio buttons if you want to offer someone the chance to "undo" a selection (or not apply a term) you need to provide an additional "term" they can select and then no save any value. It's a sort of pseudo term if you will.

Due to this, I filter the result of `get_terms()` and add a fake term with a 0 value. On save, I check for a 0 value for the term and make sure there are no terms saved for that post.

To reduce it to something y'all can test, here's an example code snippet:

```
/**
 * Add new 0 or null term in metabox and quickedit
 * this will allow users to "undo" a term if the taxonomy is not required
 *
 * @param array         $terms      Array of found terms.
 * @param array         $taxonomies An array of taxonomies.
 * @param array         $args       An array of get_terms() arguments.
 * @return array
 */
function kia_get_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) { 

    if ( isset( $args['fields'] ) && $args['fields'] == 'all' ) {

        $no_term = esc_html__( 'No term', 'my-text-domain' );

        $uncategorized = (object) array( 
            'term_id' => 0,
            'count' => 0,
            'description' => '',
            'name' => $no_term,
            'slug' => '0',
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'parent' => '0',
        );

        array_push( $terms, new WP_Term( $uncategorized ) );

    }

    return $terms;
}

add_filter( 'get_terms', 'kia_get_terms', 10, 3 );
```

In the classic editor, this works fine. But in the block editor (which still fetches the terms using `get_terms()` via the REST API... this causes an `Uncaught (in promise) error` and seems to get stuck in an infinite loop. How can I prevent this from looping?

[image: error log showing recursion]

Comment: have you considered instead replacing the panel with your own panel? I do not see the need for the pseudo-term in the block editor, it would be more effort to make it work that way than to simply eliminate it

Comment: I do replace the panel in my plugin.. i replace it with a panel of radio buttons. But with radio buttons you can't uncheck an option so you need to provide an additional radio that will stand in for "no selection". My React skills are very dodgy, so sending the extra term back in the API response _seemed_ like an easier approach to me.

Comment: You wouldn't _unset_ the radio button, that markup and those tags are determined by the state, not the other way around, so just don't set a selected option in the react component. The tags themselves are disposable, so their current state is irrelevant

Comment: I don't think I follow what you're saying. If you have radio buttons and you select "Tag A", but then later decide you want your post to have no tags, you have no way to _clear_ that selection without a "no tag" radio button. You'd have to refresh the whole editor before save, or if you've saved there's no way to undo your selection.

Comment: That doesn't mean you need an actual no tag term though. Even a clear link would work with the right event handler, or a `none` radio option with no value

Comment: TLDR: Add a hardcoded radio input named none, and when it's selected, clear the terms in the data store, fake terms are completely unnecessary

Comment: The fake terms aren't stored, but they were my original best guess at achieving what you suggest... an additional radio input with no value. Thank you for the PR! That helps explain what you were saying about hard coding the additional radio though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are passing "term_id" as 0 in your code. Use -1 instead!. It will definitely show up in the Block Editor. I guess this is a bug of Gutenberg though.

Comment: That did it!! Thank you! Could I ask _where_ that is in the code? Or how you knew that? Now I just need to adjust my save routine to make sure it handles the -1 versus the old 0.

Comment: Kind of an add on question, but if you have any insight into how to show the new radio button as checked when there are no terms for a post, that's the next thing I'm working on.